# Como saber a versão do Angular instalado pelo Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Gostaria de saber como posso descobrir a versão do Angular que estou usando?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Sem linha de comando

Pode procurar pela versão do `@angular/common` ou outra dependência do Angular no arquivo package.json em `dependencies`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
}
```

#### Com linha de comando

Na linha de comando, navegue até o diretório raiz do seu projeto Angular e execute `ng -v` ou `ng version`:

```
cd meu/projeto/
ng -v
```

A saída deve ser algo parecido com:

```
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.4.3
node: 8.4.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.6
@angular/common: 4.4.6
@angular/compiler: 4.4.6
@angular/core: 4.4.6
@angular/forms: 4.4.6
@angular/http: 4.4.6
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.6
@angular/router: 4.4.6
@angular/cli: 1.4.3
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.6
@angular/language-service: 4.4.6
typescript: 2.3.4
```

Pode ver que no meu projeto a versão do Angular é a 4.4.6.

Cuidado para não confundir a versão do `@angular/cli` com a versão do Angular utilizado no seu projeto. Se você rodar `ng version` ou `ng -v` em um diretório que não tenha um projeto Angular, ele vai retornar somente a versão do CLI.

Answer (score -2):

Na verdade, o comando a ser executado é: `ng --version`

Answer (score -4):

Para mim o comando `ng --version` funcionou

Comment: Sério? Isso já não estava escrito nas outras respostas? Veja [`ng version`](https://angular.io/cli/version). Faça o nosso [tour]

Comment: Augusto Vasques, eu apenas sinalizei que para mim o comando ng -- version funcionou, pois a resposta do Marcell Alves estava com -1 e eu não entendi o porquê. Essa foi a minha primeira postagem neste fórum e já vi que aqui é bem difícil. Ficar com menos -4 por isso, fala sério.

Comment: Se encarar o Stack Overflow como um fórum vai ser difícil mesmo. O Stack Overflow [não é um fórum ou rede social](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/137387), nós somos um site de [perguntas e respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/137387) e nosso objetivo é justamente remover a discussão ou interação entre as publicadores, pois essa só causa ruídos e debates infindáveis, transferindo essa interação para o sistema de votos. Veja [answer] e faça o nosso [tour].

Comment: PS₁: Marcelo Alves foi quem editou e melhorou a resposta, o autor foi Dom Braga. PS₂:No momento em escrevo a pergunta do Dom Braga possui 3 votos negativos e 1 voto positivo, [sumário de votos da questão](https://imgur.com/a/VKXeJoP).PS₃: Em geral o leitor do site não quer ver duas respostas iguais ou que apresente a mesma informação. O nosso leitor quer encontrar em cada resposta uma solução alternativa.